# How to retrieve the list of selected items in Finder?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, finder

From within my Cocoa app, I am trying to retrieve the list of files that have been selected in a Finder window. I have found the following way to do it, but it is unbearably slow.

```
FinderApplication * finder =
    [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.finder"];

SBElementArray * selection = [[finder selection] get];

NSArray<NSString*> * items = [selection arrayByApplyingSelector:@selector(URL)];
// now items contains the URLs as strings of all selected items
```

The most expensive call, time wise, is

```
SBElementArray * selection = [[finder selection] get];
```

The method hangs for long times when a selection is made on a large number of files, it doesn't even perform too well when working with a small selection.

Is there a better way to get the URLs of all selected files in the foremost Finder window?

I need to have the file URLs so that I can perform actions on/with those files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use apple script

```
tell application "Finder"
    get selection
end tell
```

or

```
osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\" to return selection"
```

Comment: That is the same as the code that I posted, just in script though :)
I tested the first example before I put this question here, it has the same delay associated with it. The script still goes to Finder and runs the Get command..that is what it seems to me, but nevertheless, it is still slow.

Comment: Then you need to inject code inside the finder to get the selcted items. Take a look at mach Inject.